# Dataweave get rid of empty lines when reading a file

Tags: arraylist, groovy, dataweave

I am processing a file where every other line is blank, how to get rid of these lines using dataweave or groovy? 
My payload now looks like this

[image]

my transformer which is parsing the lines is:

```
    %dw 1.0
    %output application/java
    ---
    payload map 
    {
        line: $[0]
    }
```

Thanks for the response

Comment: do you want to load all non-empty lines from file into memory? in groovy it could be like this: `List lines = new File('myfile.txt').readLines().findAll{it}`

Comment: i just want to delete lines where is {line=} eg line 1,11,13 and keep lines which have real data in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the same dataweave with filtering the payload. Check if anything in the incoming payload is empty or null kind of thing which is causing the issue.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload filter ($ !=null and $ !='')  map 
{
    line: $[0]
}
```